# Asp.net mvc 4 Application issue in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am running into this Issue on the server.

Local:

When I run my application in my local I am getting the URL as

```
http://localhost:63952/Home/Index/?Home=Home
```

On the Server:

I added the virtual directory  Called (MyDirectory)

```
   `http://10.9.29.123/Mydirectory/Home/Index/?Home=Home ( Expecting should be like this ) but I am getting 404 Error and URL coming as http://10.9.29.123/Home/Index/?Home=Home ( I do not see the Virtual directory in the URL)
```

Using VS 2013 asp.net mvc 4.5 version. ( IIS 7.5 )

Comment: Is there a question involved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your virtual directory needs to be made into an Application instead. In order to do that, open up IIS manager, navigate to your virtual directory, right-click on it, and click 'Convert to Application'. Follow the dialog that follows, according to how you want your application to be set up.